# How do I close a jquery dialog with a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, modal-dialog

I have a lot of dialogs that I need an easy solution for a close button.  I really don't want to write a ton of code to close each one.

I would like to use a class="btnDone" for all buttons and links that I want to close the dialogs.  Is there an easier way to do this other than writing a seperate function for each instance of each button in each dialog?

Here is an example of one of the dialogs code:

```
    <script>
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function() {
        $( "#forgotPassword" ).dialog({position:['middle',60],
            open: function(event, ui) {  
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span style="float:right;"><img src="../images/x.png" /></span>');  
        },  
            dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',
            modal: true,    
            autoOpen: false,
            width: '650px',
            close: function(ev, ui) {$(this).close();}
        });

        $( ".forgotPasswordOpen" ).click(function() {
            $( "#forgotPassword" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="forgotPassword">
        <!--#include file="modal08.asp"-->
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I write the close function with a class="btnDone"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
   $( ".btnDone" ).click(function() {
       $(this).parent().dialog( "close" );
   });
</script>
<div id="forgotPassword">
   <input type="button" class="btnDone" value="Done" />
</div>
<div id="forgotUsername">
   <input type="button" class="btnDone" value="Done" />
</div>
```

Assuming the button is within the dialog, all you'd need to do is make a call to the button's .parent() to reference that specific dialog.

I've not used jQuery UI before though, so have no idea if "close" is what you'd pass to the dialog to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close)?  It's just like opening one

```
$( ".btnDone" ).click(function(){
  $('.ui-dialog-content').dialog( "close" );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to have a master buton that closes all the dialogs. If each dialog contains a button styled as `.btnDone`, such as:

```
<div>
My great dialog
<button class="btnDone">Get outta here</button>
</div>

<div>
Another thought
<button class="btnDone">Close</button>
</div>

<div>
Check this out
<button class="btnDone">Away!</button>
</div>
```

You could use `$('.btnDone').parent('div').dialog('close');` to close, or `$('.btnDone').parent('div').hide();` to hide, all the dialogs.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/PHcL4/1/ for a working example.